# Destructuring Actions in Nested Redux Reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, state

I'm dispatching an action that looks like this:

```
{ type: "TOGGLE_FARA", fara: true, id: "5d20d019cf42731c8f706db1" }
```

The "id" is merely used for identifying the correct user. The action is meant to modify the "enabled" property of my "fara" state. The fara section of my store looks like this:

```
{
   fara: {
     enabled: false, // This need to be flipped...
     names: []
   },
   senators: {
      enabled: false,
      names: []
   },
   senateCandidates: {
      enabled: false,
      names: []
   }
}
```

However, I'm not sure how to structure my reducer. I only want to change the "enabled" property. I've tried a few different ways:

```
export default (state = DEFAULT_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case "INITIALIZE_SETTINGS":
        return {
          fara: action.fara,
          senators: action.senators,
          senateCandidates: action.senateCandidates,
          emails: action.emails
        }
      case "TOGGLE_FARA":
        return {
          ...state,
          // fara['enabled']: action.fara <–– This won't compile...
          // 'fara.enabled' : action.fara <–––This just gives me a key name with the string 'fara.enabled' 
        }
      default:
        return state;
      }
```

I was going to do something like this, but this modifys the state directly which you aren't supposed to do (my redux tool extension says the states are the same, which is not ideal). Any thoughts?

```
export default (state = DEFAULT_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case "INITIALIZE_SETTINGS":
        return {
          fara: action.fara,
          senators: action.senators,
          senateCandidates: action.senateCandidates,
          emails: action.emails
        }
      case "TOGGLE_FARA":
        state.fara.enabled = action.fara;
        return {
           ...state
        };
      default:
        return state;
      }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will work:

```
return {
          ...state,
          fara: { ...state.fara, enabled: action.fara }
        }
```

and apparently is even in the [Redux documentation](https://redux.js.org/recipes/using-object-spread-operator)

Comment: Apologies, the "default" state that I punched in initially was wrong. The "fara" key is a key within my "settings" object, which is why I'm having difficulty...

Comment: @HarryCramer Not sure I got your schematics but does that edit help?

Comment: Hmm, not quite... I just tried to clarify the initial state. It's a big object, where fara is a single key. Don't think what you provided targets "fara" specifically... I'm imagining it would look something like: { ...state, fara: /// something here? }

Comment: @HarryCramer Seems like I confused "fara" and settings but it should work otherwise